# I can't get message in laravel view method return

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to get a message which i have return with larevel view return with method but when i get this message variable it is not display.

I have created API for paytm paymentgetway .

## code are bellow

web.php

```
Route::get('/book/{id}/{title?}','BooksController@bookDetail');
```

api.php

```
Route::post('payment/status', 'OrderController@paymentCallback');
```

## controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use PaytmWallet;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\EventRegistration;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use View;
use Cookie;
use URL;
 public function paymentCallback(Request $request)
{
    $data = Session::all();
    $transaction = PaytmWallet::with('receive');
    $response = $transaction->response();
    $order_id = $transaction->getOrderId();

    $resultsdata = DB::select('select * from tbl_payment where order_id = "'.$order_id.'"');

    $msg = "";
    if($transaction->isSuccessful()){
        $aUpdate = DB::table('tbl_payment')->where('order_id',$transaction->getOrderId())->update(['payment_status'=>"success"]);
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        // $userid =  Session::get('userId');
        // $ebook_id =  Session::get('ebook_id');
        // $payment_id =  Session::get('payment_id');

        DB::table('mb_user_purchase_ebook')->insert(['ebook_id' => $resultsdata[0]->ebook_id,'user_id' => $resultsdata[0]->user_id,'coupon_id' =>"0",'payment_id' => $resultsdata[0]->payment_id, 'createddate' => $currentDate ]);
        $msg = "jignesh";
    }else if($transaction->isFailed()){
        $aUpdate = DB::table('tbl_payment')->where('order_id',$order_id)->update(['payment_status'=>"fail"]);
        $msg = "kanu";
    }
    $bookdata = DB::select('select * from mb_EBuuk120610 where ebook_id = "'.$resultsdata[0]->ebook_id.'"');

    Session::flash('messageDATA', 'Successfully deleted the nerd!');

    return redirect()->to('/book/'.$resultsdata[0]->ebook_id.'/'.str_slug($bookdata[0]->ebook_title_eng,'-'))->with('message',"Thish is my message");
    // dd($transaction);
}
```

When i trying to fetch message variable in view or controller but not give me any output so can any one help on this.
I have trying all possible things but its not give me output.

Comment: Your code has a bug

Comment: What bug in code?

Comment: See my answer please.

Comment: Please post the code you use to fetch the message in your view.

Comment: {{ Session::get('message') }}